# Can we conserve momentum when friction is acting

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, friction

Let us say, there is a block and a plank, there is friction between these two surfaces, now the block starts moving with a velocity, now according to me, friction acts backwards on the block and forwards on the plank. Hence net force on the system is zero, and the momentum can be conserved. But it doesn't make physical sense to me, that momentum can be conserved. Can someone give me a concrete answer and a reason?

Comment: You have explained *exactly* why the momentum of the whole system is constant - because the force exerted by the block on the plank is equal and opposite to the force exerted by the plank on the block (Newton's Third Law). So any change in momentum of the block is cancelled out by an equal and opposite change in momentum of the plank. What doesn't make "physical sense" to you ?